# Graphviz portability and fonts. How make schemes identical on different OSs?

Tags: fonts, graphviz, portability, dot

I'm working with Graphviz on Mac but most of my apps run on servers with Ubuntu. I've noticed that dot-schemes with the same source code are drawn a bit differently when compiled on different operating systems.

It seems to me that the main reason is the difference between fonts on the systems. Even though I use the same generic fonts and same sizes — they appear too different which affects the layout a lot.

**So the question is:** is it possible to make fonts look identical in Graphviz schemes across the systems?

Below I attach the examples demonstrating the problem. Images are attached as links for convenience.

Source code:

```
digraph {
    graph [label="Mac" labelloc=t]
    dpi=100
    pad=0.2
    rankdir=LR
    a [shape=rect label="width=1" width=1]
    b [shape=rect label="width=1.5 Arial" width=1.5 fontname=Arial]
    c [shape=rect label="width=2.7 Arial 20" width=2.7 fontname=Arial fontsize=20]
    d [shape=rect label="width=4 Helvetica" width=4 fontname=Helvetica]
    e [shape=rect label="width=5 Helvetica 25" width=5 fontname=Helvetica fontsize=25]
    f [shape=rect label="width=6, blue 0.8, red 0.2" width=6 style=filled color="blue:red;0.2" fontcolor=white]
}
```

- [Generated on Mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWocI.png)  graphviz version 2.40.1
- [Generated on Ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVnPA.png)  graphviz version 2.40.1
- [Generated on Windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOKUD.png)  graphviz version 2.38

As you can see on the schemes — the font is not the only problem: filling with two colors looks a bit different on Mac\Ubuntu and Win10. But this specific issue may be because I have graphviz 2.38 on my Windows machine.

And now the same scheme but without node labels:

```
digraph {
    graph [label=Mac labelloc=t]
    dpi=100
    pad=0.2
    rankdir=LR
    a [shape=rect label="" width=1]
    b [shape=rect label="" width=1.5 fontname=Arial]
    c [shape=rect label="" width=2.7 fontname=Arial fontsize=20]
    d [shape=rect label="" width=4 fontname=Helvetica]
    e [shape=rect label="" width=5 fontname=Helvetica fontsize=25]
    f [shape=rect label="" width=6 style=filled color="blue:red;0.2" fontcolor=white]
}
```

- [Generated on Mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flhdq.png) graphviz version 2.40.1
- [Generated on Ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYlR7.png) graphviz version 2.40.1
- [Generated on Windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0iWb.png) graphviz version 2.38

Here the resuts are almost identical (except the damn colorlist)

Comment: How are you saving the images generated?

Comment: @tk421 with the same command: `dot -Tpng input.dot -ooutput.png`

Comment: You could generate PNGs on the preferred platform and use the images everywhere else.

Comment: @tk421 that's a solution! But unfortunately, the very idea of using Graphviz in my projects is that I can avoid keeping schemes in static PNG files. I design my schemes on MAC but compile them automatically in Ubuntu container. But they could be also compiled on any other machine since it is a git-repository

Comment: You might also want to look at https://superuser.com/questions/305953/how-to-get-osx-ttf-fonts-into-linux if you want to keep fonts consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to be with graphviz version which is bottled in [Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/graphviz#default). Graphviz is very strange there, especially it doesn't include Cairo engine and really has some problems with fonts.

So I have removed Homebrew version and installed Graphviz from [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=graphviz). Now the font sizes when I build images on Mac are almost the same as on Ubuntu and Windows. The fonts are not perfectly the same but they are close enough for the development process.

[Same image generated by Graphviz from MacPorts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6qBD.png)