# Node distance doubles inside clusters

Tags: graphviz

I'm automatically generating Graphviz `.dot` files from a diagrams tool for an OOP language. Some diagrams use clusters to represent e.g. files that contain several entity (e.g. object) definitions. Trouble is, inside the clusters the node distance doubles, which results in very large diagrams. A simple example:

[image]

Note how the edge labeled "extends" is twice as long as all the other edges.

The source code for this simple example is at https://gist.github.com/pmoura/a3092a95eb5c2cd06e02735230a8b8ec

A more complex example that I think have the same root cause:

[image]

Is there a solution to make the distance between the nodes inside a cluster the same as the distance between a cluster node and a node outside the cluster? For some reason, `dot` is aligning cluster edge labels with outside nodes, as you can see in the attached image. Please note that I'm looking for a solution that can be automated, not a fix for a concrete diagram. Things that I tried  to no avail include `newrank` (which always seg faults) and edge `constraint`. The only workaround I found was not to use clusters, which prevents me exporting SVG files with URL links to files and directories in source code repos.

The source code for this second attached graph is at https://gist.github.com/pmoura/c12a9ce94f9a0b872c60087ac40c2975 (too big to paste it here).

Comment: Seen your reputation why didn't you add the dot / source code?

Comment: @albert Source size. But I added a link to a gist with it to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more digging on Graphviz resources, it turns out that this issue is caused by a bug, fixed in the current git version, and not by a graph parameterization issue. The bug ticket is available at:

https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/issues/1288

The bug is present in the current (2.40.1) stable release and on the current (from the official website) `graphviz-2.41.20171026.1811.tar.gz` development snapshot.

P.S. I'm on macOS and usually install Graphviz using MacPorts. But, as of this writing, MacPorts `graphviz-devel` portfile installs the snapshot above, which doesn't include the bug fix. I ended up using Homebrew to easily compile and install the current Graphviz git version (`master` branch) using the command `brew install --HEAD graphviz`.

Comment: Thank you for research, I struggled with this bug too. Unfortunately graphviz version in Homebrew is very strange, on my Mac machine it messes with fonts a lot, which seems to be because of this version is missing Paco or something like that. So be careful. You can look at my question about that issue to see examples of what goes wrong in brew graphviz: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54743233/graphviz-portability-and-fonts-how-make-schemes-identical-on-different-oss

Answer (score 1):

Sorry it appears we haven't refreshed the official devel snapshot since 2017! We are struggling a little with some website issues since we moved to a free account on gitlab and don't have shell access, thus it is difficult to do things like programmatically generate new content. Maybe someone can advise us if it is possible to get an inexpensive paid account on gitlab with shell access. I did call them once but ended up talking with a rep who didn't know and wasn't motivated to help. It is frustrating for everyone I know.

Comment: Clueless rep. Sad. It would be a nice gesture and marketing move for GitLab to sponsor the Graphviz project by offering a lifetime paid account.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible workaround would be to use [xlabels](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:xlabel) or [headlabel](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:headlabel) \ [taillabel](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:taillabel) with manual positioning instead of `label`. That is not very convenient but leaves the edge lengths intact.